# Typescript and ThreeJS, add to the scene inside loader

Tags: typescript, three.js

I have the following code:

```
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit {
scene: THREE.Scene;
(...)
 ngOnInit() { 
(...)
this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
(...)
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("../../assets/fire_lion.json",function ( obj ) {
    this.scene.add( obj ); // The line that's giving me trouble
});
```

The scene is defined and working, but when I try to run this code, I get an error which says that the scene isn't declared. It makes sense, since "this" no longer references the class, but how can I add the object to the scene then?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Using ObjectLoader simply gives me an error message saying I should be using JSONLoader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this in load callback has changed. Need to call bind or use TypeScript syntax which transpiles to bind call.

```
loader.load("../../assets/fire_lion.json",function ( obj ) {
    this.scene.add( obj );
}.bind(this)); // bind here
```

or

```
loader.load("../../assets/fire_lion.json", ( obj ) => {
    this.scene.add( obj );
}));
```

Comment: That was absolutely correct! Due to how Three.js works, I had to make a slight change to the second code snippet, but the logic was all you.

In order to add an Object to the scene, it must be converted into a mesh, so you can add materials if you want to.
The code that worked is as follows:

https://pastebin.com/RdEnttaH